# Elastic Search: Search in single and given documents

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have indexed multiple (500) documents to ES with a "content" field with different files text in each index.

```
POST /megacorp/employee113
POST /megacorp/employee114
POST /megacorp/employee115
```

I would like to search for the word or phrase in many documents say in 150 documents. I tried "POST /megacorp/employee115,employee116/_search" like this. But I have to search in 150 documents. Is there any other way?

UPDATE:
**

```
'POST /megacorp/employee114/7
{
    "first_name" :  "Douglas",
    "last_name" :   "Fir",
    "age" :         35,
    "about":        "I like to 158 build cabinets",
    "interests":  [ "forestry" ]
}'
```

** Here is the sample mapping. In the same way I have around 150 document indexed. Now I would like to perform a search in say 40 documents. I know we can keep a comma between each document like I said in original post. I would like to know if there is any better way than this.

Comment: Please show some sample documents, the mapping type for your document, and also it's not clear what you mean by "I have to search in 150 documents". Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: 'POST /megacorp/employee114/7
{
    "first_name" :  "Douglas",
    "last_name" :   "Fir",
    "age" :         35,
    "about":        "I like to 158 build cabinets",
    "interests":  [ "forestry" ]
}' Here is the sample mapping. In the same way I have around 150 document indexed. Now I would like to perform a search in say 40 documents. I know we can keep a comma between each document like I said in original post. I would like to know if there is any better way than this.

Comment: Thanks. You should update your question so it's more readable.

Comment: updated in main question